# Choosing feature selection method

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I have a dataset that contains input features of type numerical as well as in the form of Boolean (0 and 1). My ouput is either 0 or 1 (classification). I want to ask what feature selection techniques can I use before applying different machine learning classifiers on my data?

Comment: why would you do that? what are your goals?

Comment: Hi. Thankyou for your response, I have a medical dataset and I have to predict disease using ML classifiers (0- disease, 1-No disease). I have 13 features. I want to apply feature selection technique so as to get importance of features. I am thinking of using Anova f-test. My question is can I use Anova f-test for the given dataset?

Comment: computing variable importance is a different task, that can't logically be the goal of feature selection, the other way around is fairly common instead. Statistical tests are an option, another popular solution, more ML oriented, is random forest feature importance.

Comment: HI, thankyou for your suggestions. My goal actually is to predict accuracte with least number of possible features available to me. Practical implementation of it like in case of medical data where we can predict accuractely for a disease with least number of features.